# Уменьшение размера скомпилированного файла

Tags: java

Всем привет! Столкнулся с такой ситуацией:

```
public static final String index2 = "HUGE STRING CONSTNT2"
```

эта переменная огромного размера используется в другом классе. Компилятор ее копирует и получаем файл слишком большого размера.
Первый вопрос, связано ли это с кейвордом *final*?

*Oracle* предлагает так решать проблему :

```
private final static String index2;
static {
   index2 = "HUGE STRING CONSTNT2"
}
```

Строка все равно осталась финальной, как это решение поможет?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом варианте компилятор Java использовал тот факт, что поле `index2` объявлено как `final`, имеет тип `String` (строки в Java, как известно, неизменяемые) и получает своё значение во время компиляции. Это позволило компилятору заменить обращение к этой константе в другом классе на значение этой константы. Аналогичные оптимизации компилятор может произвести с примитивными типами (`int`, `float`, `char` и т. д.) и их обёртками (`Integer`, `Float`, `Character` и т. д.) так как он точно уверен в том, что эти типы неизменяемые.

Во втором варианте значение `index2` на этапе компиляции неизвестно, поэтому компилятор вынужден вставлять в код класса обращение к ней. При этом корректность кода не нарушается - блок `static` выполняется при загрузке класса до создания любого из его экземпляров, поэтому при первом использовании поле `index2` будет иметь значение.

Comment: а если убрать кейворд *final* у поля, он сделает оптимизацию ведь?

Comment: Без модификатора `final` у программы появится возможность менять `index2` во время выполнения (имеется ввиду возможность заменять объект, на который ссылается `index2`, а не изменять саму строку), поэтому вшивать полученное при компиляции значение `index2` в другой класс Java не будет.